# Synchronizing Javascript structures with server-side with JSON Rest

Tags: javascript, ajax

I wanted to find out frameworks or libraries for synchronizing Javascript structures with a server using JSON, REST, ajax. On the server side I'm using PHP and codeigniter.

Basically I have different Javascript "objects" which I would like to serialize into JSON and send to the server for update in the database preferably with very little code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at Backbone: http://backbonejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here's Douglas Crockford's official stringifier/parser for JSON.
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js.

Comment: let me check it out. Thanks!